# На собеседовании задали такие вопросы , как бы вы ответили?

Tags: javascript, php

Вопрос №1 Достоверно известно, что некоторый API периодически отваливается по таймауту или с 5хх ошибкой. Аналогов нет, заменить данный сервис нечем. Использование этого API критически важно для асинхронных задач внутри приложения. Что будем делать? Какие библиотеки и паттерны будем использовать чтобы минимизировать потери и повысить стабильность приложения? *
Мой ответ

Вопрос №2 В ответ на входящий вебхук приложение должно сделать несколько запросов в БД, пару запросов к стороннему API, вернуть 200OK в ответ на вебхук вне зависимости от результатов вышеперечисленных запросов. Сервис, дергающий вебхук, требует чтобы ответ пришел в течение трех секунд. Что будем делать? *

Answer (score 4):

1. **Паттерн Command** инкапсулирует запрос как объект, позволяя тем самым задавать параметры клиентов для обработки соответствующих запросов, ставить запросы в очередь или протоколировать их, а также поддерживать отмену операций.
   Паттерн «Команда» позволяет спрятать действие в объекте и отвязать источник этого действия от места его исполнения. Классический пример — проектирование пользовательского интерфейса. Пункт меню не должен знать, что происходит при его активизации пользователем, он должен знать лишь о некотором действии, которое нужно выполнить при нажатии кнопки.

   Когда использовать Паттерн Command
   Когда необходимо обеспечить выполнение очереди запросов, а также их возможную отмену.
   Когда надо поддерживать логгирование изменений в результате запросов. Использование логов может помочь восстановить состояние системы - для этого необходимо будет использовать последовательность запротоколированных команд.
   Когда необходимо параметризировать объекты выполняемым действием, ставить запросы в очередь или поддерживать операции отмены (undo) и повтора (redo) действий.
2. "вернуть 200OK в ответ на вебхук вне зависимости от результатов вышеперечисленных запросов." - обработать запрос и поставить в очередь, после вставки в очередь отправить сообщение 200OK с номером сообщения, что далее можно было вытащить данные с этого запроса. Далее каждое сообщение обрабатывается поочерёдно в заданной последовательности (асинхронно). т.е. 1. запрос получили 2. ответили вот вам номер в очереди. 3. обработка очереди. 4. Если нужны результаты запроса отправляйте отдельно запрос по номеру в очереди.

---

Очереди в случае обоих вопросов можно организовать на основе СУБД, kafka, или другого постоянного хранилища, чтобы в случае падения нашего приложения сообщения не терялись.